# Route issues while using nested_attributes in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use a single form to send data to two tables: Questions and Answers.

To do so, I am using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` as [outlined here](https://masonoise.wordpress.com/2010/07/23/rails-and-forms-using-accepts_nested_attributes_for/). Here is my **Question.rb** model:

```
  class Question < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_many :answers
   belongs_to :category
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :allow_destroy => true
 end
```

Then in my `_form` view, I am using:

```
 <% form_for(@question, :url => question_path(@question)) do |f| %>
    <% f.text_field :question_text %>
 <% f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>
 <%= builder.text_field :answer_text %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

This produces a confusing error: `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"questions", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]`.

Even if I manually append an id onto the params (like http://localhost:3000/triviabuilder/new?id=1), I still receive this error.

Do I really need to specify an ID in the params, and if so, should that be done in the controller?

**EDIT - Adding Routes.rb**

```
 Example::Application.routes.draw do

   resources :games

   resources :questions

   resources :answers

   resources :triviabuilder 

   devise_for :users

   root "pages#home"
   get "triviabuilder" => "triviabuilder#index"
   get "new_triviabuilder" =>"triviabuilder#new"
```

**EDIT 2 - Adding TriviaBuilder Controller**
*Tries to call the Question table since it includes nested_attributes*

```
 class TriviabuilderController < ApplicationController
     def new
        @question = Question.new
     end

     def create
        @question = question.new(params[:question])

        if @question.save
            redirect_to triviabuilder_path,  :notice => "Your post was saved"
         else
           render "new"
         end
       end
      end
```

This is producing a "show" error for `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"triviabuilder"} missing required keys: [:id]`.

Comment: you have mentioned show action's path after submitting the form..that is why it is giving you an error

Comment: `<% form_for(@question) do |f| %>` change the line as I have mentioned

Comment: Please show your **routes.rb**

Comment: @dkp, just added to op. Thanks

Comment: @darkginger routes is fine. Just check your **create** action in your controller. If you are redirecting to **show** action from **create** action, then you need to pass the question object or id to it. It would be good if you could show the **create** action as well.

Comment: @dkb Added the controller code since that seems to be my mistake. Tried appending an id on the params but still producing error above. Example: `http://localhost:3000/triviabuilder/new?id=2`

Comment: try to redirect to `question_path(@question)` because triviabuilder_path's show action needs an id to redirect to particular triviabuilder object

Answer (score 1):

Try changing following things

**routes.rb**

```
resources :triviabuilders
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(Question.new , url: triviabuilders_path) do |f| %>
  <% f.text_field :question_text %>
  <% f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>
   <%= builder.text_field :answer_text %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller name should be plural**, change to `TriviabuildersController` from `TriviabuilderController`.

`create` action should be as follows:

```
def create
    @question = Question.new(params[:question])
    if @question.save
        redirect_to triviabuilders_path,  :notice => "Your post was saved"
     else
       render "new"
     end
   end
```

Comment: The page now loads, though the forms do not (it shows the h2 text in the view but the form is not rendering). I am debugging now but I will let you know if I figure it out.

Comment: @darkginger thats simple. Make sure you have used <%= %> tag for your **form_for** instead of <% %>.  Check my answe above.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line of code from `form_for`

```
:url => question_path(@question)
```

Also, you need to add `=` to your `form_for` tag otherwise it won't be visible, Your `form_for` should look like this

```
<%= form_for @question do |f| %>
```

Rails will automatically map it to the `update` action.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Gave it a shot. When I make that exact update, it's running into a new error: `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`. I am wondering if it's because I don't have a new action in my controller.

Comment: In the error above, I removed all of my controller code. If I create a ` new` method like with: `def new    @question = Question.new    end`, it shows error nearly identical to the original problem: an issue with the show action. Thanks!